# Classification model on large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, classification, large-data

I would like to implement a classification model on a dataset where n=3000000 and 12 columns. I have a problem because it's very slow after hours I don't get anything, do you have a recommandation to run it faster ?

Thaks

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(3000000, 12)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKL'))
X=df.drop(['L'], axis=1)
y=df['L']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

parameters = {'n_neighbors':np.arange(1,30)}
grid=GridSearchCV(KNeighborsClassifier(),parameters,cv=5)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: can you brief me about the number of classes? their ratios in dataset? Also, using KNN for 1-30 is very high. Instead, try using up 1,10,30. If you get 10. Then try 5,10,15 & likewise

Comment: You're doing 150 different calls to `fit` on 3 million rows of data, with a classifier that takes a lot of memory space, with no parallelization. That's just going to be slow.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand very well your question but  I generated a random dataset of int64 with 12 columns each columns has the same weight in the dataset.

Comment: @G.Anderson, is there a way to go faster but I cannot work at all on a dataset of this size.

Comment: As @MehulGupta said, `'n_neighbors':np.arange(1,30)` is too large a search space for your `GridSearch`, try steps to narrow it down as they suggested; do a lower `cv=` number, change `n_jobs` to allow parallel processing as one answer suggested

Answer (score 0):

Use more cores i.e. use `n_jobs=-1` within `GridSearchCV` and `KNeighborsClassifier`.

```
parameters = {'n_neighbors':np.arange(1,30)}
grid=GridSearchCV(KNeighborsClassifier(n_jobs=-1),parameters,cv=5, n_jobs=-1)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Hello it's still very slow unfortunately

Comment: you can also reduce the grid space: `'n_neighbors':np.arange(1,30)`

Answer (score 0):

Another answer besides cutting down on the high number of neighbors: build a model from a smaller sample of the data. If `KNeighborsClassifier` does not look promising on one million observations, it might not be worth the time and resources to try it on three million.